# Need postgres statement that returns non unique records even if I pass same ids in array

Tags: postgresql, select

For Example, the following query

```
SELECT id, name, price 
from tennis_ticket 
where id=ANY('{3,3}')
```

**returns:**

```
 id |     name     | price 
----+--------------+-------
  3 |       Eighty |    80
(1 row)
```

**What I want is:**

```
 id |     name     | price 
----+--------------+-------
  3 |       Eighty |    80
  3 |       Eighty |    80
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join against the array:

```
select tt.*
from tennis_ticket tt
  join unnest(array[3,3]) x(id) on x.id = tt.id;
```

or use a `values` clause

```
select tt.*
from tennis_ticket tt
  join (values (3), (3)) as x(id) on x.id = tt.id;
```

Comment: select tt.*
from tennis_ticket tt
  join unnest(array[3,3]) x(id) on x.id = tt.id;

This solved my purpose. Thanks